# GWT's analog for Android LinearLayout's layout_weight property?

Tags: java, android, gwt, web-frontend

Android's LinearLayout individual children android:layout_weight attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. How can I get the same children size adjustment in GWT's VerticalPanel or HorizontalPanel?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think in GWT but in HTML.

I also think it is better to work with divs in this case.
Maybe checkout some library like GWT bootstrap, or GWT DominoUI

I think this thread actually gives an HTML answer to what you want: [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Translating this into a GWT project should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Dmitry this can be done in HTML using the css grids, check out how this feature is implemented in domino-ui [Grids](https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#grids)

Comment: @AhmadBawaneh This only is horizontal fill I think and not vertical ?

Comment: [Grid layout](https://dominokit.github.io/domino-ui-demo/index.html?theme=indigo#grid-layout) can be used for both , or even a combination of grids and grid layout.